# Select everything after the last space using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with an address database using PostgreSQL 9.5 and trying to create a select statement where only the names of the streets and not the types are returned. So if I have a record that says: 'Golf Course Rd', I only want to get back: 'Golf Course' or if the record is 'Bentwood Rd', I only want 'Bentwood' returned.

Any suggestions on how to tackle that?

Comment: Could you give us real test data, are you working with real addresses or you just want to clip off "Rd."?

Comment: I have voted to close this. I like my answer a lot but perhaps it's better elsewhere. Others do not read this question the same way and as is I can't *prove* them wrong. We need more information.

Answer (score 7):

This is a question [address canonicalization and parsing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/165915/2639). Essentially what you're talking about is handled through a [gazetteer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazetteer) (geographical rule set). There are two ways to do this right,

1. [`address_standardizer`](http://postgis.net/docs/Address_Standardizer.html) from the PostGIS project and certainly better if you're only using United States addresses.
2. [`pgsql-postal`](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-postal) may be a better method for international addresses.

I'll show the address standardizer version for the address,

```
Chicken Ranch
10511 Homestead Rd
Pahrump, NV 89061
```

Using `standardize_address` from `address_standardizer`, returns a composite type of [`stdaddr`](http://postgis.net/docs/stdaddr.html)

```
SELECT * FROM standardize_address('us_lex',
   'us_gaz', 'us_rules', '10511 Homestead Rd, Pahrump, NV 89061');
 building | house_num | predir | qual | pretype |   name    | suftype | sufdir | ruralroute | extra |  city   | state  | country | postcode | box | unit 
----------+-----------+--------+------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+-------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-----+------
          | 10511     |        |      |         | HOMESTEAD | ROAD    |        |            |       | PAHRUMP | NEVADA | USA     | 89061    |     | 
(1 row)
```

So you can see, `ROAD` is pulled out in `suftype`

[*Based on this q/a*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/165915/2639)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the content of your question, you want everything before the last space... right?

One way would be to use regular expressions:

rextester: http://rextester.com/YIZT9659

```
with foo as (
  select 'Fizz Buzz Rd'::text as foo
)
select regexp_replace(foo, '(.*)( .*?)', '\1') as StreetName
from foo as bar
```

returns: `Fizz Buzz`

Answer (score 3):

Sequence of characters (`.*`) followed by a space ().
The matched expression within the (first) brackets is being returned. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

```
select substring ('Fizz Buzz Rd' from '(.*) ')
```

> Fizz Buzz